# Showing that $x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$ implies $f$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a connected convex open subset with $(0, 0) \in E$, and $f(x, y)$ be a differentiable function on $E$. Suppose $f$ satisfies $$x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$$ then prove $f$ is constant on $E$.

---

We are given $E$ is convex and connected with $(0,0) \in E$, so it only seems natural to start with a line from the origin to $(x, y)$. Let this be $\gamma(t) = (tx, ty)$. We wish to show that the derivative across this line is zero so that $f(0,0) = f(x,y)$. So, take $h(t) = f(\gamma(t))$ and $h'(t) = f'(\gamma (t))\gamma'(t)$.

Now

$f'(\gamma (t)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$

$\gamma'(t) = \gamma$ since $\gamma$ is a linear operator.

Now do I just say that the whole thing equals to zero and be done with it?

Comment: Let me give you something to think about: What if $f(x,y)=g(y/x)$, where $g$ is any differentiable function? Then $xf'_x+yf'_y=xg'(y/x)\cdot(-y/x^2)+yg'(y/x)\cdot 1/x=0$. Now, why isn't this a counter example to your statement? (Oh, question closed... Well, I will let this comment stand)

Answer (score 0):

You shoud be more careful with your notation, which is wrong at some points. In particular, $f'(\gamma(t))$ should be a vector and not a number.

Another thing: your differential equation reads
$$x \, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) + y \, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) = 0.$$
In particular, there are the same $x$ and $y$ in front of the derivatives and as arguments, where the derivative is evaluated. This is wrongly used in your proof.

Comment: Your answer is missing a $y$ in front of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.  You say that this is wrong, but it does seem to be what @Soke intended.

Comment: @LSpice: This was just a typo, sorry and thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Okay, so multiply by $t$. What do I do about $\gamma'(t)$?

Comment: I do not know, what you mean. $\gamma'(t) = \gamma$ is ok, since $\gamma$ is linear.